# Sector of a circle

Tags: circles, coordinate-systems

[image]

My method:-
I have tried many ways but i did not get any answer
so i used a scale and a compass and constructed the circle and took angle to be $Tan^{-1}(4/3)$ in a circle of radius 2 units
and got the answer to be $0.5$
but the actual answer is D

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

From the construction, if $H$ is the orthogonal projection of $F$ on $OA$,  we have $\overline{HF}=\frac{1}{2}\overline {DB}$, so:
$$
\frac {\overline{HF}}{d}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\overline{DB}}{d}=\frac{1}{2}\sin \theta = \sin \alpha
$$
where $\alpha$ is the arc $AF$. and $\theta$ is the arc $AB$ (see the figure)

[image]

So : $\alpha=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\sin \theta \right)$

Comment: AF=1/2 AB SO AF/AB=0.5?

Comment: Sorry! There was some confusion with the points. I edit and I hope it's better now :)

Comment: but why are my theoritical values wrong?

Comment: Maybe that your angle is a special case solution ( I've not verified, but you can if you want). The general solution is as in my answer. I add a figure.